# Solve a quadratic integral equation

Tags: calculus, integration

I am a not completely familiar with all rule of integral. Is it possible to show me the rules? We have a function $z(t)$. We know that:
$$z = \int 2z^2(t)dt$$
Is it possible to find function $z(t)$?
Is it possible to help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Since $z$ is an integral, it is continuous. Since $z$ is continuous then $\int 2z^2$ is differentiable. Take derivatives on both sides: $z'=2z^2$. There is the solution $z(t)=0$. Otherwise $z'/z^2=2$. Integrate, $-1/z=2t+C$, which gives $z=-\frac{1}{2t+C}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to deal with a differential equation. You obtain one by taking the derivative,

$$z'(t)=2z^2(t).$$

This is a separable equation, so that

$$-\frac{dz}{z^2}=-2\,dt$$ and

$$\frac1z=C-2t,$$

$$z=\frac1{C-2t}.$$

---

As we can verify,

$$2\int\frac{dt}{(C-2t)^2}=\frac1{C-2t}+C'$$ and we take $C'=0$.

Comment: can you explain second equation?

Comment: @Amin: sorry, there was a typo, $dt$ missing.

Comment: Thanks. It is good too.

Answer (score 0):

Take $z(t) = \frac{1}{-2t}$, then $z'(t) = \frac{2}{(-2t)^2}=2z(t)^2$

Therefore

$$\int_{-\infty}^{t}z'(t)= z(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t}2z(t)^2 $$